# Python - Force an error if an undeclared variable is used inside a class

Tags: python, class, class-members

Consider the following Python code:

```
class a_class:
    defined_var = 1

    def a_function(self):
        self.defined_var = 2
        self.undefined_var = 3
```

The possibility to assign a value to a variable (and then implicitly declare it) that I did not declared at the beginning of the class (like I do for
`undefined_var` in the previous example) is creating me several problems, since for huge classes I forget what I define and I what I don't.

I know that this question may sound silly. I've used to develop using C/C++/Java for a long time where the definition of variables in a class is mandatory...

Is there a way to avoid this? I mean, I would like a behavior like in C/C++/Java where I get an error if I use an undefined variable.

Comment: You may try to use a linter like [pylint](https://docs.pylint.org/en/latest/technical_reference/features.html) to get this result.

Comment: @Ankirama thanks, this is also very interesting!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, python instances have a [`__dict__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#object.__dict__) - a dictionary that stores all of the object's attributes. This is what allows them to store arbitrary attributes. You can suppress the creation of the `__dict__` by defining [`__slots__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#slots). This is a class-level variable listing the names of all attributes instances of the class can have. If a class has `__slots__`, trying to assign to an undefined attribute will throw an exception.

Example:

```
class MyClass:
    __slots__ = ['defined_var']

    def a_function(self):
        self.defined_var = 2

obj = MyClass()
obj.a_function()
obj.undefined_var = 3  # throws AttributeError
```

Comment: Plus for mentioning `__slots__`, useful tip.

Answer (score 4):

You can override [`object.__setattr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setattr__):

```
class a_class:
    defined_var = 1

    def a_function(self):
        self.defined_var = 2
        self.undefined_var = 3

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        if hasattr(self, key):
            object.__setattr__(self, key, value)
        else:
            raise AttributeError(f"\"{key}\" is not defined in \"{self.__class__.__name__}\"")

a = a_class()
print(a.defined_var)
a.a_function()  # <-- throws an error
```

**P.S.** `defined_var` is class variable shared by all instances. It means that all changes will affect all instances of class (maybe it's not what you're expecting). More information [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables).

Comment: Thanks a lot! +1! Anyway, this code produces an error: 

`$ python test.py 
1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 16, in <module>
    a.a_function()  # <-- throws an error
  File "test.py", line 5, in a_function
    self.defined_var = 2
  File "test.py", line 10, in __setattr__
    object.__setattr__(self, key, value)
TypeError: can't apply this __setattr__ to instance object`

Comment: The version I'm currently using is 2.7.12

Comment: For python2 replace `object.__setattr__` with `self.__dict__[key] = value`. Or add inheritance from object in class definition `class a_class(object):`.

Answer (score 2):

Just add some Notes here:

The creator of Python, Guido van Rossum, states that he actually created **slots** for faster attribute access.

from book **fluent python**, `__slots__` is used for faster attribute access and reduce memory usage not to prevent the user from adding more attributes.

check this code:

```
class MyClass:
    __slots__ = ['defined_var', '__dict__']

obj = MyClass()
obj.undefined_var = 3  # works fine
```

The problem in using `__slots__`,If you create a subclass of this class you need to repeat the `__slot__` attribute in it too.

```
class MyClass:
    __slots__ = ['defined_var']

class MySubClass(MyClass):
    # you need to redefine the __slots__ here too
    pass

obj = MyClass()
sub_obj = MySubClass()
sub_obj.undefined_var = 3  # works fine not excepting this
obj.undefined_var = 3  # throw exception
```

So If you really need this go with overriding the `setattr` method as @Olvin Roght suggested.

```
class MyClass:
    x = None 
    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        if hasattr(self, key):
            object.__setattr__(self, key, value)
        else:
            raise AttributeError(f"\"{key}\" is not defined in \"{self.__class__.__name__}\"")


class MySubClass(MyClass):
    pass


obj = MyClass()
sub_obj = MySubClass()
sub_obj.x = 3  # works fine
obj.x = 3  # works fine
sub_obj.undefined_var = 3  # error
obj.undefined_var = 3  # error
```

If some day you want to do monkey patching on your object:

```
obj = MyClass()
obj.__dict__['z'] = 4
print(obj.z)  # print 4, we added a new attribute
```

So don't worry about preventing the client from adding new attribute it's a bad habit. and you will prevent your self from controlling your object and change its behavior, removing the flexibility that python give you, why would you want that.

Comment: Nice answer. Thanks a lot. I want this kind of "prevention" because it is a mess if a don't use a super-mega-iper-giga powerful IDE which remembers me what I've implicitly declared.

Comment: Pycharm is an excellent IDE whith beautiful auto compilation you will love

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Anyway, I think that a good language should be usable even with a simple notepad and a terminal. Also, I think that developers should be aware of what he/she is doing. Too much freedom is dangerous. Just an opinion!

Comment: I'm coming from Java background coding in Python is like art, You will code even in the weekend just give it some time, and read books like,  learning python, fluent python, python in nutshell, and python cookbook you will learn the force of this language good luck.

Comment: maybe I still need time to digest the new paradigm :D